# How to get access viewcell by index from ListView object in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to get **Viewcell**(view) of listview in xamarin forms by index, i tried a lot  as below code

```
var myViewCellList = mListView.ItemTemplate.values; 
//this return Dictionary with 0 elements
```

it may look like 
      `var view = mListView.ItemTamplate[index];`

Comment: You want acess to the ViewCell or to the object binded to the List?

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround to get the viewcell by passing item index, not the better way but this works if we dont have any alternate.

```
MyListView.NotifyRowTapped(selectedTimeCardIndex);

 private void ViewCellTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
   if(sender is ViewCell viewCell)
   {
     //viewCell for the selected index
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I just got solution of this problem by myself while using **ITemplatedItemsView** interface by customising the ListView

For more discussion visit [Here](https://www.google.com)

```
    public class CustomViewCell: ListView
   {

       public ITemplatedItemsList<Cell> TemplatedItem
       {
           get { return ((ITemplatedItemsView<Cell>)this).TemplatedItems; }
       }        
   }
```

Implementation :

```
var viewcell = (CustomViewCell.TemplatedItem[0] as viewcell);
```

Comment: I down voted this answer, because this may work for you, but it's not how you typically access the view items. Without better understand what you are trying to do. this is giving people the wrong idea about how to access views.

Comment: @Neil It was your responsibility to answer before criticizing , if you already know it is not better way