# How to get ListView item index from custom ViewCell in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, listview, xamarin, indexing

I created a ListView that have a custom ViewCell as below:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" ItemTapped="ListView1_ItemTapped"
SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="192" HasUnevenRows="False"
FlowDirection="RightToLeft" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <custom:ViewCell1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and here is the XAML for the custom ViewCell

```
<ViewCell.View>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding ID}" />
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Text="Get index" Clicked="Button1_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
```

All I need is when I click on Button1, I get the ListView1 item index (or ViewCell index)

The problem is I can't access ListView1 from Button1_Clicked event from the code behind in the custom ViewCell and gets tapped item index of ListView1 (or even gets ViewCell tapped item index).

I searched a lot, and found that it can be done by 3 ways:

1- Create an attached property for the ViewCell to get its index.

2- Use indexer for the ViewCell and get its index.

3- Use ITemplatedItemsView interface as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719124/how-to-get-access-viewcell-by-index-from-listview-object-in-xamarin-forms)

But unfortunately I couldn't implement any of them from Button1_Clicked event in the custom ViewCell code behind because I'm not an expert in either MVVM or C#.

Can I have an expert assistance please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways which can implements it . If you are new to data binding and MVVM. I will provide the easiest way .

Firstly , add a property in the model of ItemSource .

```
public class YourModel
    {
        public int Index { get; }

        //other properties like name and ID
        public YourModel(int index)
        {
            Index = index;
        }
    }
```

And set the value of **Index** when init the ItemSource of ListView .

```
sources = new ObservableCollection<YourModel>() { };

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   sources.Add(new YourModel(i) { /**other propertes**/});
}
```

In CustomCell

Get it like following

```
var model =  this.BindingContext as YourModel;
int index = model.Index;
```

Comment: Many Thanks Lucas for your simple answer, that exactly what I needed. I'm initializing the itemsSource on OnAppearing() event from the content page which contains the ListView...do you suggest I should initialize it from the OnAppearing() event of the custom ViewCell so I can use the BindingContext ?

Comment: You just need to get the bindingcontext in click event .

Comment: Thanks Lucas, actually I load only 10 records then when it reaches the scroll ends it fetches the next 10 from the database, will this makes duplicates in index numbers in i values?   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)

Comment: Set the index start from  the current length -1 of the ItemSource .

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue . If you have more question, you could create a new thread with more details so that I can help you better .

Answer (score -2):

try using `Button1.Parent.Parent.Parent...` and so on, unless you get your `listview`'s object.

Also pass `BindingContext` of `viewcell` in button's `CommandParameter` like `CommandParameter={Binding}` and then get the index of your received object from `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks Prayag for your fast response, can you please explain more about getting the index of received object from ItemsSource